# Eclipse plugin default dialogs localization

Tags: eclipse, localization, eclipse-plugin

I make localization of my custom Eclipse RCP plugin and want to see default Search and Import/Export wizards translated, but currently I can't switch it to my language (Russian). I already install Babel package to my RCP dev platform and got localized UI in host system, but plugin still not translated. How I can do it? All my custom messages and plugin.xml localized already with internal wizard.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to run your application with argument -nl ru
did you reload your target platform? Preferences->Plugin-in Development ->Target Platform, select your target platform and click "Reload" button
wish I could help more.
goodluck